# Microsoft graph api for getting userinfo giving error

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

After OpenID authentication with Microsoft Azure AD while system tries to get the user details with https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo Microsoft server throws below error.

[image]

```
  << "x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_22","ADSiteName":"NCU"}}[\r][\n]"
  << "Duration: 1.2061[\r][\n]"
  << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000[\r][\n]"
  << "Date: Mon, 06 May 2019 06:47:24 GMT[\r][\n]"
  << "[\r][\n]"
  << "102[\r][\n]"
  << "{[\r][\n]"
  << "  "error": {[\r][\n]"
  << "    "code": "InternalServerError",[\r][\n]"
  << "    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",[\r][\n]"
  << "    "innerError": {[\r][\n]"
  << "      "request-id": "45bf81f5-bcf7-4661-b69b-48947bdd76fe",[\r][\n]"
  << "      "date": "2019-05-06T06:47:24"[\r][\n]"
  << "    }[\r][\n]"
  << "  }[\r][\n]"
  << "}[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: Could you please add your request sample so that I can reproduce it. Thanks

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Please see the above screenshot.. Additionally I can confirm that if I hit microsoft south Indian data center it is working .  Problem is with specific data centers. Is there any braking changes ? Thanks

Comment: Let me confirm if there are any. But I guess it should not be. Thanks.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron this is bug in the system and MS engineering are working on it

Comment: Sounds good.... Thanks for your information.

Comment: @ArunKillu Sorry to bring this back up again, I'm seeing issues again. How did you contact Microsoft Engineering?

Comment: Yes this issue has started again, I don't know who is handling this at Microsoft. Whoever it is he is too adventurous and fixing something in production 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some news from Microsoft engineering team. It seems that this was an internal change that impacts AAD tokens that hits some datacenters. They are preparing a hotfix that will be deployed Thursday(9th may 2019) morning PDT, so everything should be fixed by that time.

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing literally thousands of errors like below when calling: https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo

and it seems random based on which server receives the request.

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
request-id: 253ceb44-8a32-4335-97b2-b776dfb8f6b3
client-request-id: 253ceb44-8a32-4335-97b2-b776dfb8f6b3
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"East US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_26","ADSiteName":"EUS"}}
Duration: 1.283
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Wed, 08 May 2019 13:53:53 GMT
Content-Length: 258

{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "253ceb44-8a32-4335-97b2-b776dfb8f6b3",
      "date": "2019-05-08T13:53:54"
    }
  }
}

Is there a link where I can see when that fix has been deployed that's scheduled for Thursday(9th may 2019) morning PDT as this is greatly impacting our business?

Comment: You can use comment for asking this.

Comment: There is no link I got official mail communication as I have raised the ticket with Microsoft

Comment: Thanks Arun... It wouldn't let me comment btw as I didn't have enough "reputation" to comment.

Comment: This has affected lot of corporate customers and the problem is only with some data centers . hope things will be OK by today .

Comment: FYI... still no Hotfix yet.